# Utility of duplicate champions?

Tags: marvel-contest-champions

Starting the game, I got Iron Man 1*, then at the end of the tutorial, I got a bonus 2* crystal, which gave me a 2* Iron Man.

Despite having two Iron Man in my team, is there any utility to have duplicate champions? Like echanging one for another hero, or fusing them for a more powerful Iron Man?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the game definitions you don't have a "duplicate". You actually have two champions of different tiers (number of stars).

You'll duplicate a champion when you get twice the same champion of the same tier. If you get a second 2* Iron Man you'll have a duplicated champion.

Dupped champions (as people call them) have awaken abilities. The color of the stars on your champion avatar will change from golden to silver. I remember that when I first started playing the game I thought it was very confusing that when your champion gets better it goes from golden to silver. Usually we see examples of the opposite happening.

Anyways, so your first duplicate of a champion will awaken his/her signature ability. Iron Man signature ability is Arc Overoad, which is basically regeneration when his life is low. Every time you dupe your Iron Man again, his signature ability level will increase.

1* champions do not have signature abilities. Dupping them don't change anything.

Unfortunately you cannot fuse champions to get a better one. I wish we could. So basically your 1* Iron Man won't be very useful now that you got a 2*. But you can still use your 1* for very specific reasons. 1v1 arena or sandbagging is what comes to my mind now.

You cannot exchange champions directly. But you can sell them and get shards that you can use to buy crystals. And then get other champions by opening crystals. There are countless discussions both on Reddit and on official forums about selling vs not selling champions. I'm team "never sell a champion".

So to summarize my answer "just keep your 1* on your team if one day you need them for any reason they will be there".

Answer (score 1):

Additional utility is only gained if the champions have the same number of stars. In this case they gain abilities which become more powerful with more duplicates.